# How do I print area from a text area in Java?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have a swing component called `statsText` in Java. This contains text inside of it and I want the user to be able to print the data displayed in `statsText` with a printer.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
java.awt.Component.print(statsText.getText());
```

So what do I need to do?

Comment: Please look at the [Print Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = statsText.getText();
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText(text);
boolean success = textPane.print();
if (success) {
    /* show a success message  */
    ...
} else {
    /*show an error message */
}
```

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi the method `print()` does not exist on `String`. Your code does not make much sense

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: I skipped the TextPane code line in hurry, updated now. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your statsText object is of type JTextComponent, which includes JEditorPane, JTextArea and JTextField, then it has several print methods which [are demonstrated in Oracle's Java tutorials for printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html). A trivial example derived from the information on that page is

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PrintExample {
    static JTextArea text = new JTextArea("Print this text");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
           text.print();
       } catch (PrinterException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

If your needs are more involved than the trivial example covers, further options are documented in the Java SE javadocs for JTextComponent, where, for example, you'll find an overloaded method that allows you to describe headers and footers for a print job, whether a system print dialog should be shown, and others.